# Create new object in win 8 store app

Tags: c#, xaml

Im trying to implement a simple create-function in my win 8 app. Im trying to use the MVVM-pattern. Im trying to pass a class into my view with my view.model and then simply have a couple of textboxes that lets me create a new object. Here is the ViewModel and class:

```
public class CreateViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public Place Place { get; set; }
}

public class Place
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int PlaceId { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

In an MVC-application i would have done some `@Html.TextBoxFor` and created a post-method.
In XAML I am not sure of how to do this. 
The viewmodel gets passed in to view as it should. I can acess its properties like this:

```
 <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Path=Place.Title}"/>
 <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Path=Place.Description}"/>
```

But i do not understand how I can "post" new values back to the ViewModel and create a new object?

EDIT:

From what I can see this is a way to have commands in my ViewModel:

```
public class CreateViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public RelayCommand CreatePlaceCommand
        {
            get; 
            private set;
        }

        public Place Place { get; set; }

        public CreateViewModel()
        {
              InitializeCommands();
        }

        private void InitializeCommands()
        {
            CreatePlaceCommand =
                new RelayCommand(() =>
                {
                    //What goes here?
                });
        }
    }
```

I also added this code to my XAML:

```
 <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Place.Title,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Place.Description,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    <Button Grid.Row="0" Content="Click"
             Command="{Binding CreatePlaceCommand}" >

    </Button>
```

Am I on the right track here? Its pretty confusing =)

Comment: In mvvm/xaml you don't post anything. Values are just one/twoway databound to underlying properties. Maybe you could add button that is attached to "CreatePlace" command.

Comment: Thank you! Ok.
And "CreatePlace" is a method on my ViewModel?

Comment: No, preferably it's a command if you follow MVVM.

Comment: Please se Edit if you can.

Comment: Code that creates place goes into lambda.

Comment: Ok, That should mean that I do:
var newPlace = new Place(){Here I want to set the properties, but how since I do not post anything?}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, study this simple example to get hold of MVVM/DataBinding/Commands. It's really simplistic but it should show the "patterns" to use. There's plenty of libs (like MVVMLight) to make commanding etc. simpler and more powerful.

So assuming we have `Place` entity

```
public class Place
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("Id={0},Title={1},Description={2}", 
            Id, Title, Description);
    }
}
```

And you have `MainWindow.xaml` in your application named `wpfApplication1`

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:wpfApplication1="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Height="116"
        Width="250">

    <!-- set datacontext to mainviewmodel -->
    <Window.DataContext>
        <wpfApplication1:MainViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="30" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!-- input textboxes for title and description -->
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0">
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Place.Title, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Height="25" />
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Place.Description, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Height="25" />
        </StackPanel>

        <!-- button bound to save command, declared in viewmodel -->
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="Save" Command="{Binding SaveCommand}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Related `MainWindows.xaml.cs` contains nothing but `InitializeComponents()`.

Now your `MainViewModel`, "taking care of all things", could look like

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    private Place _place;

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        // create and register new save command
        SaveCommand = new SaveCommand(this);
        CommandManager.RegisterClassCommandBinding(
            typeof(MainViewModel), new CommandBinding(SaveCommand));
    }

    // property to hold place data, exposed in UI
    public Place Place
    {
        get { return _place ?? (_place = new Place()); }
        set { _place = value; }
    }

    public ICommand SaveCommand { get; private set; }
}
```

And simplistic save command implementation used in viewmodel

```
public class SaveCommand : ICommand
{
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
    private readonly MainViewModel _context;

    public SaveCommand(MainViewModel context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Do something with {0}", _context.Place));
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Now, this would give you UI, something like below (this example is not type of Store app)

[image]

And clicking a button would then spit out

```
Do something with Id=0,Title=Title,Description=and teh description
```